# Why there is a 'MACH' in this Compressibility Correction Chart?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, chart-supplement

[image]

I couldn't find what 'Mach 1.0' and 'Mach 0.8' are trying to indicate in the middle of the chart.

Can anybody explain about this please?

Answer (score 1):

As I read it, the upper arch pointed to by `Mach 1.0` represents the correction necessary at the different pressure altitudes when flying at Mach 1.0, while the lower arch pointed to by `Mach 0.8` represent the correction necessary at those pressure altitudes when flying at Mach 0.8.

i.e. the correction necessary at 30,000 feet at Mach 1.0 is roughly -30, while the correction at that same altitude but Mach 0.8 is only roughly -15.

Answer (score 0):

The M 1 curve is uncorrected calibrated airspeed at the speed of sound at various pressure altitudes and is the limit of the chart, and the M .8 curve is the uncorrected calibrated airspeed at M .8 at the various pressure altitudes, roughly (M# is actually a function of temperature; pressure alt is used as a substitute based on standard atmosphere temperature and lapse rate).

They are just there for reference.  If use of the chart required the precise plotting of Mach # as a parameter, there would be an array of Mach # plots, not just the one at .8.